# Based on your development stack, which is easier for you and why? Debugging or logging?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, language-agnostic, logging, aop

1. Please state if you are developing on the **front end**, **back end**, or if you are developing a **mobile/desktop application**.
2. List your development stack

   - Language, IDE, etc..
   - Unit Testing or no Unit Testing
   - Be sure to include any AOP frameworks if used.
3. Tell me if it is easier for you to use a debugger or to using logging during development, and why you feel it is easier.

I'm just trying to get a feel for why people choose to use a debugger or logging based on their development stack.

Comment: Um, why? Is this strictly a programming-related question? Maybe the CW might be a better place for this?

Comment: @Jonners Why? Because I'm just trying to get a feel for why people choose debugging or logging based on their development stack.

Comment: @leeand00 Why do you think it is related to the development stack?

Comment: @Neil Because of what I learned about AOP and logging.  It's much easier to use AOP to add and remove your logging statements, then it is to enter and remove them manually.  

Some development stacks do not support AOP.  

However, there are some places where all you can do is log because a debugger cannot follow you there in certain stacks (anonymous functions for instance).

Comment: @Jonners...This question is Community Wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Front end and Back end. Desktop]

As usual: it depends....

Debugging is better if you are investigating behaviour at a distinct place in the code and/or you don't know what objects you will need to inspect and you don't mind interfering with the natural speed/order of code flow

Logging is better if there is a known variable or variables you need to monitor often over a wide swath of the flow AND when you want the code to run naturally without  interruptions. Logging is also a useful addition to unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on the type of problem. A lot of the work that I do currently is done on the back-end (C#, WCF-services). I typically find it easiest to use logging to get a rough idea on where and when a problem occurs, then I try to tailor a test that provokes the behaviour, and then use debugging in order to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I mainly use logging and unit testing, though I think my greatest weakness as a programmer is that I am not proficient in using gdp. I can do the basic stuff (breakpoints, watches) but don't really know enough to really tap into the power it really has.

Answer (score 0):

I feel some discord in the question. Debugging—according to Wikipedia—is:

> Debugging is a methodical process of
>   finding and reducing the number of
>   bugs, or defects, in a computer
>   program

Logging is an automatic writing of trace text records while program is running.

So I use logging as a *part of debugging*. And I think many people are. Otherwise, what are logs were made for? Well, maybe for further numeric analysis, but that's another story.

Comment: @Nailxx If debugging isn't using a program to monitor the steps of a program and the values of the variable, then what should I call it?  

"Using a debugger" ?

Comment: @leeand00 definitely it is more precise term